# Light weight file replication

Tags: windows, replication

I have a request to create a back up web server, my idea is to copy all the web sites files from the source to the destination on some predefined schedule.

Does anyone have any recommends for utilities or methods to do this?

Two that have been mentioned in the office are

1. Robocopy
2. secure FTP

Answer (score 1):

robocopy is my preferred way on Windows. I've also had some good experience with synctoy
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=E0FC1154-C975-4814-9649-CCE41AF06EB7&displaylang=en

and if you prefer using the classic toold, like rsync, here's a good link:
http://www.rsync.net/resources/howto/windows_rsync.html

Comment: +1 for SyncToy. Robocopy and DeltaCopy / rsync seems to get confused with hard links, so be wary of that.

Comment: Is there a way to make the copy process secure? as the file transfer would be between machines in DMZs

Comment: I'd suggest setting up an ssh tunnel. The rsync article I've posted above also suggests some ways

Answer (score 0):

You *could* run rsync from within Cygwin, but it can be massively variable in efficiency